# Kotlin: setTheme not changing the theme colors (transparent)

Tags: android, kotlin, themes

How to change the theme by programmatically?

1. Style

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="Pet.Theme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme.NoBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

2. Manifest

```xml
<activity android:name="com...PetTransparentActivity" />
```

3. Activity

```kotlin
class PetTransparentActivity : PetBaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (missionArgs.isTransparent) {
            Log.d("Activity", "Transparent")
            setTheme(R.style.Pet_Theme_Transparent)
        } else {
            Log.d("Activity", "Not Transparent")
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoBar)
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.pet_activity_transparent)
        startScreenNavigation()
    }

}
```

When I run above code, the theme not changed. But If changed the theme from `manifest`, it's working.

```xml
<activity
            android:name="com...PetTransparentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Pet.Theme.Transparent"/>
```

How to make my code work so I can change the theme from `PetTransparentActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not best but work for me.

I fix it with create another activity that support for transparent or not transparent.

- ActivityA (Transparent using AndroidManifest.xml)
- ActivityB (Not Transparent using AndroidManifest.xml)

Both activity **replace same Fragment**.

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
if (missionArgs.isTransparent) {
    Log.d("Activity", "Transparent")
    setTheme(R.style.Pet_Theme_Transparent)
} else {
    Log.d("Activity", "Not Transparent")
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoBar)
}
```

after
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Comment: Still not working